# PHP session isset() syntax check

Tags: php

I am trying to do the following:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['members']||$_SESSION['FBID'])){
}
```

I am getting an unexplained syntax error. Is this code invalid?

Comment: Are you sure this gives you a syntax error? It looks like a semantic error to me (ie. `if(isset(true)) {` which is not allowed.

Comment: @Halcyon Dead sure it gives me a syntax error I can paste the image for you...I even tried this on a clean page with no other code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't combine syntax like that within a language construct. In this case you need two separate `isset` calls with your logical `or` between them

```
if(isset($_SESSION['members']) || isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir that did it for me...will accept when time expires +1

Answer (score 0):

Correct Ans is,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['members']) || isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
}
```

You can't combine both variable for one condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just use separate `isset()` for both variable check. cause in `isset()` you can't use condition or compare as a function parameter. you can only pass a variable to get true or false.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['members']) || isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
}
```